# Not Able to Change Transitions in Revolution Slider

Tags: jquery, html, slider, revolution-slider

First I created my own slide show but could not set transitions, because showing only fade effect.  Slider have data-kenburns effect and after include it in code other transition effects stop and i cat not see where is the problem with code.
Please advise. 
Here is a code for slider:

```
if($homeSliders)
            {
                echo ' <div class="tp-banner-container">
            <div class="tp-banner" >
                <ul>    <!-- SLIDE  -->';
                foreach ($homeSliders as $homeSlider)
                {
        ?>
                    <li data-transition="<?= $homeSlider->effect->title ?>" data-slotamount="1" data-masterspeed="1500" data-delay="10000" data-saveperformance="off" data-title="Latest Collections" data-kenburns="on" data-bgposition="left top"
                        data-bgpositionend="center top"
                        data-bgfit="200"
                        data-bgfitend="100"
                        data-duration="200"
                        style="background-color: #F6F6F6;" >
                        <img src="<?= $homeSlider->getImg($homeSlider->id) ?>" alt="kenburns1" data-bgposition="center bottom" data-bgpositionend="center top" data-kenburns="on" data-duration="10000" data-ease="Linear.easeNone" data-scalestart="100" data-scaleend="120" data-rotatestart="0" data-rotateend="0" data-blurstart="0" data-blurend="0" data-offsetstart="0 0" data-offsetend="0 0" class="rev-slidebg" data-no-retina >
                        <div class="tp-caption <?=$homeSlider->title_show?> tp-resizeme revo-slider-caps-text uppercase"
                             data-x="450"
                             data-y="150"
                             data-speed="400"
                             data-start="1000"
                             data-easing="<?=$homeSlider->title_show?>"
                             data-splitin="none"
                             data-splitout="none"
                             data-elementdelay="0.01"
                             data-endelementdelay="0.1"
                             data-endspeed="1000"
                             data-endeasing="Power4.<?=$homeSlider->title_show?>" style=""><img src="<?= $homeSlider->getImgProduct($homeSlider->id) ?>" alt="<?=$homeSlider->title?>"></div>
                        <?php if ($homeSlider->title) { ?>
                        <div class="tp-caption <?= $homeSlider->title_show ?> tp-resizeme revo-slider-emphasis-text nopadding noborder tp-resizing-positions"
                             data-x="<?=$homeSlider->title_top?>"
                             data-y="<?=$homeSlider->title_left?>"
                             data-speed="700"
                             data-start="1200"
                             data-easing="easeOutCubic"
                             data-splitin="none"
                             data-splitout="none"
                             data-elementdelay="0.01"
                             data-endelementdelay="0.1"
                             data-endspeed="1000"
                             data-endeasing="Power4.easeOutCubic" style=" color: <?=$homeSlider->title_color?>; max-width: 730px; width: auto; white-space: normal; line-height: 1.15; font-size: <?=$homeSlider->title_size?>px!important; min-width: 250px;"><?=($homeSlider->title ? $homeSlider->title : '' )?></div>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <?php if ($homeSlider->description) { ?>
                        <div class="tp-caption customin <?= $homeSlider->description_show ?> tp-resizeme revo-slider-desc-text tp-resizing-positions"
                             data-x="<?=$homeSlider->description_top?>"
                             data-y="<?=$homeSlider->description_left?>"
                             data-speed="700"
                             data-start="1400"
                             data-customin="x:0;y:150;z:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:1;scaleY:1;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:200;transformOrigin:50% 0%;"
                             data-easing="easeOutCubic"
                             data-splitin="none"
                             data-splitout="none"
                             data-elementdelay="0.01"
                             data-endelementdelay="0.1"
                             data-endspeed="1000"
                             data-endeasing="Power4.easeOutCubic" style="text-align: left; color: <?=$homeSlider->description_color?>; max-width: 550px; white-space: normal; font-size: <?=$homeSlider->description_size?>px!important;"><?=($homeSlider->description ? $homeSlider->description : '')?></div>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <?php if ($homeSlider->link) { ?>
                        <div class="tp-caption <?= $homeSlider->button_show ?> tp-resizeme tp-resizing-positions"
                             data-x="<?=$homeSlider->button_top?>"
                             data-y="<?=$homeSlider->button_left?>"
                             data-speed="700"
                             data-start="1550"
                             data-easing="<?= $homeSlider->effect->title ?>"
                             data-splitin="none"
                             data-splitout="none"
                             data-elementdelay="0.01"
                             data-endelementdelay="0.1"
                             data-endspeed="1000"
                             data-endeasing="Power4.<?= $homeSlider->effect->title ?>" class="button button-border button-large button-rounded tright nomargin hero-action-btn"><span style=" color: <?=$homeSlider->button_color?>; font-size: <?=$homeSlider->button_size?>px!important; background-color: transparent !important; border: 2px solid #22afeb; padding: 0.5em 2em !important; border-radius: 5px !important; line-height: 1.3em !important;"><a href="<?= $homeSlider->link; ?>" >more</span> <i class="icon-angle-right"></i></a></div>
                        <?php } ?>
                    <?php
                    echo '</li>';
                }
                echo '</ul></div></div>';
            }
```

and this is my script code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery('.tp-banner').show().revolution(
                    {
                        dottedOverlay:"none",
                        delay:16000,
                        startwidth:1140,
                        startheight:600,
                        hideThumbs:200,

                        navigationType:"bullet",
                        navigationArrows:"solo",
                        navigationStyle:"preview4",

                        navigation: {
                            keyboardNavigation:"on",
                            keyboard_direction: "horizontal",
                            mouseScrollNavigation:"off",
                            onHoverStop:"off",
                            touch:{
                                touchenabled:"on",
                                swipe_threshold: 75,
                                swipe_min_touches: 1,
                                swipe_direction: "horizontal",
                                navigationType:"bullet",
                                drag_block_vertical: false
                            }
                            ,
                            arrows: {
                                style:"zeus",
                                enable:true,
                                hide_onmobile:true,
                                hide_under:600,
                                hide_onleave:true,
                                hide_delay:200,
                                hide_delay_mobile:1200,
                                left: {
                                    h_align:"left",
                                    v_align:"center",
                                    h_offset:0,
                                    v_offset:0
                                },
                                right: {
                                    h_align:"right",
                                    v_align:"center",
                                    h_offset:70,
                                    v_offset:0
                                }
                            } ,
                            bullets: {
                                enable: true,
                                container:"slider",
                                hide_onmobile: false,
                                style: "ares",
                                hide_onleave: false,
                                direction: "horizontal",
                                h_align: "center",
                                v_align: "bottom",
                                h_offset: 0,
                                v_offset: 30,
                                space: 3,
                                rtl:false,
                                tmp: ''
                            }
                        },
                        touchenabled:"on",
                        onHoverStop:"on",

                        swipe_velocity: 0.7,
                        swipe_min_touches: 1,
                        swipe_max_touches: 1,
                        drag_block_vertical: false,

                        parallax:"mouse",
                        parallaxBgFreeze:"on",
                        parallaxLevels:[7,4,3,2,5,4,3,2,1,0],

                        keyboardNavigation:"off",

                        navigationHAlign:"center",
                        navigationVAlign:"bottom",
                        navigationHOffset:0,
                        navigationVOffset:0,

                        soloArrowLeftHalign:"left",
                        soloArrowLeftValign:"center",
                        soloArrowLeftHOffset:0,
                        soloArrowLeftVOffset:0,

                        soloArrowRightHalign:"right",
                        soloArrowRightValign:"center",
                        soloArrowRightHOffset:20,
                        soloArrowRightVOffset:0,

                        shadow:0,
                        fullWidth:"on",
                        fullScreen:"off",

                        spinner:"spinner4",

                        stopLoop:"off",
                        shuffle:"off",

                        autoHeight:"off",
                        forceFullWidth:"off",

                        hideThumbsOnMobile:"off",
                        hideNavDelayOnMobile:1500,
                        hideBulletsOnMobile:"off",
                        hideArrowsOnMobile:"off",
                        hideThumbsUnderResolution:0,

                        hideSliderAtLimit:0,
                        hideCaptionAtLimit:0,
                        hideAllCaptionAtLilmit:0,
                        startWithSlide:0,
                        fullScreenOffsetContainer: ".header"
                    });
            });
```